# TeXworks Access Denied

Tags: miktex

Every time I try to edit a latex doc and run it I get an error that says `"Cannot write file "C:/Users/..." Access is denied`. Are there any settings I need to change to be able to edit a document and save it?
Thank you!

Comment: If you're using a PDF viewer to see your file at the time of compilation, perhaps this viewer is protecting it from rewriting. Try closing viewers first.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio s comment is especially true for Adobe Acrobat,TeXworks' internal viewer and alternative viewers like Sumatra do not care if the file they are showing is refreshed in the background. Another hint: sometime *latex.exe instances remain open if there are errors in the file and the compilation process is not stopped correctly. Happens me from time to time when I use build tools like Arara.